# Extract multiple columns with single dynamic array formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

In Excel 365, how can I select non-contiguous columns from a range using a single dynamic array formula? Consider data in columns `A:E` as follows:

[image]

Entering `=XLOOKUP(G1,A1:E1,A2:E11)` into cell `G2` returns the column labeled `col2`. But `=XLOOKUP(G1:I1,A1:E1,A2:E11)` returns the first entry of the those three columns instead of the entire columns. How can I understand this behavior? What's an alternative?

I can similarly retrieve a single column but not a group of columns with `INDEX`/`XMATCH` or `FILTER`:

`=INDEX(A2:E11,0,XMATCH(G1,A1:E1))`

`=FILTER(A2:E11,A1:E1=G1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `0` for the rows, use `SEQUENCE` to return an array of numbers to the INDEX:

```
=INDEX(A2:E11,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:E11)),MATCH(G1:I1,A1:E1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This works! Do you know why using a `0` instead of `SEQUENCE()` forces implicit intersection and returns a single row?

Comment: @bkraines nope, I thought it should work.

Comment: Apparently `0` doesn't work because "arrays of arrays" are not yet supported: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6BbkjWGXNs

Comment: Ahh, that would make sense.  By using `SEQUENCE` we are creating a 2D array.  But by using `0` it creates a 1 dimensional array of 3 1 dimensional arrays.  Thanks for finding that.